# Не работает SQLite в aiogram

Tags: python, sqlite, aiogram

Пишу:

```
@dp.message_handler(text = 'Проверка')
async def privet(message: types.Message):
   cur.execute("SELECT id FROM podpiska WHERE dt == datetime.date.today().day AND oplata == 0")
   result = cur.fetchall()
   await bot.send_message(result)
```

Выдает:

```
  File "C:\Users\Anna\Desktop\python\рр\bot.py", line 33, in privet
    cur.execute("SELECT id FROM podpiska WHERE dt == datetime.date.today().day A
ND oplata == 0")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

Comment: Что-то я не припоминаю такой штуки в sqlite `datetime.date.today()`

Comment: это из модуля datetime. так нельзя делать?

Comment: Неа, нельзя ___

Comment: а как тогда сравнить переменную из бд с какой-то внешней переменной?

Comment: [вот так](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#:~:text=returned%20as%20str-,cur.execute(%22select%20%3F%22%2C%20(AUSTRIA%2C)),-row%20%3D%20cur)

Comment: мне это ничем не помогло

Comment: `cur.execute("SELECT id FROM podpiska WHERE dt == ? AND oplata == 0", datetime.date.today().day)`

Comment: спасибо, теперь заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@dp.message_handler(text='Проверка')
async def privet(message: types.Message):
    cur.execute("SELECT id FROM podpiska WHERE dt == ? AND oplata == 0", datetime.date.today().day)
    result = cur.fetchall()
    await bot.send_message(result)
```